# Export Wiki Page to PDF?

Tags: wiki-pages

Do you have any tips or solutions for exporting Wiki Page to PDF? I am using SharePoint 2013. No Enterprise Wiki Site collection. I don't want any 3rd party tool for this. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

**In short,**  There is **no** direct option to export the WIKI page to PDF!

**Workaround**

- Open your page.
- Click Crt + P.
- Then select your destination to `Save to PDF` as shown below

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's what I had in mind before, but I am looking for the links in the PDF that should be clickable or working somehow. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome, In this case, you can use js code in a script editor, check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896592/is-it-possible-to-save-html-page-as-pdf-using-javascript-or-jquery but Ctrl + P is the best option, it doesn't print the **left navigation**!

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution :

Solution taken from - [Click here for original post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/thomsven/2011/09/09/export-sharepoint-wiki-to-wordpdf-without-3rd-party-tools/)

Kindly follow the steps for exporting SharePoint Wiki to Word/PDF without 3rd party tools -

First, we added three additional fields to our Wiki library:

[image] 
All these fields were added to the standard view, and we created a datasheet view for more efficient setting of these values.
Then we created a new view, called "PrinterFriendlyView" as follows:

1. Remove all columns except "Wiki Content"
2. Set sorting to use the "Printout..." fields described above
3. Set filter to be "Printout in System Documentation" = "yes"
4. Set "Style" to "Newsletter"
5. Set "Item Limit" to 999

   [image]
   Open this new view, and follow these steps:

   1. Mark all the text (this is a little awkward, I found it easiest to start from the bottom and go upwards)
   2. Open a blank document in Word and paste in all the content
   3. You will probably get some warnings, where clicking "No" is probably the best (I didn't test clicking "Yes")
      Warning text: "This operation will require copying many styles. Do you want to use Normal style instead?"
      Warning text:
   4. Change "Verdana, font 16" to "Heading 1" style (this may differ for your wiki - hopefully you have some consistent formatting for page headings that you can use)
      a. Open the "Search/replace" dialog in Word
      b. Click on "Replace"
      c. Click on "More"
      d. Click in the "Replace with" box and then click the "Format" button at the very bottom. Choose "Style -> Heading 1"
      e. Click in the "Find what" box and then click the "Format" button at the very bottom. Choose "Font -> Verdana, 16pt"
      f. Click "Replace All"

[image]

5. Modify the style for "Heading 1", paragraph setting, to include a
   page break before each occurrence.
6. Go to the start of the document
7. Add a heading:"System Documentation", using "Title" style
8. Add a text underneath: "Table of Contents, using "SubTitle" style
9. Underneath, include a Table of Contents, using these steps (assuming Word 2010): a. In ribbon, click "References" b. Click
   "Table of Contents" c. At the bottom of the list, click "Insert
   Table of Contents..." d. In the creation dialog, set "Show levels"
   to 1, and click OK. e. Verify that the table of contents makes
   sense, you may, e.g., have some extra paragraphs marked as "Heading
   1" where they should not have been.
10. Choose "Save As" and set format to PDF.

Comment: I did a few times but it's not working.